# Correlated subquery in order by clause in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I had a query similar to the following and was wondering that DB2 complained about the correlation use in the ORDER BY clause. It errored with something like

> [42703][-206] "A.ID" is not valid in the context where it is used..
>   SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703

I was able to rewrite the query to avoid the correlation usage but I couldn't find a reference in the documenation about this. Is this a bug or am I just not able to find details on the expected behavior?

```
SELECT a.id
FROM A a
ORDER BY (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   B b
  WHERE  b.id = a.id
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use correlated query  in order by clause. However there is many ways to get same result, for example

```
select count(*) as count_num ,a.ID 
from
   a join  b on  a.ID=b.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
order by 1 DESC
```

Comment: Do you know if this is a general SQL limitation or is that just DB2 specific? I'd like to understand the reasons if there are any. I am correlating on a column that is available in the projection so I don't see a reason for it not being possible to work.

Comment: Ahh, there it is. I was desperately looking for the term "order" but the documentation actually says a correlated subquery can only appear in the SELECT or WHERE clause: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_181.htm

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:

```
SELECT a.id, (select count(*) from B where B.id=a.id) nbOFB 
FROM A 
order by 2
```

Comment: Thanks but that won't work when wanting to use the value in an expression like e.g. `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 0):

solution 2:

```
select * from (
SELECT a.id, (select count(*) from B where B.id=a.id) nbOFB 
FROM A
) tmp 
order by nbOFB
```

Comment: Thanks for all the possibilities, but I was seeking an answer to why this isn't allowed rather than possible alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3:

```
SELECT a.id, c.nb 
FROM A 
inner join lateral
 (
   select count(*) nb from B where B.id=a.id
 ) c on 1=1
order by c.nb
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 4 :

```
SELECT a.id, ifnull(c.nb, 0) nb 
FROM A 
left outer join 
(
   select b.id, count(*) nb from B group by b.id
) c on a.id=c.id
order by ifnull(c.nb, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 5:

```
with c as (
select b.id, count(*) nb from B group by b.id
)
SELECT a.id, ifnull(c.nb, 0) nb 
FROM A left outer join c on a.id=c.id
order by ifnull(c.nb, 0)
```